# How to check if a file on a network location is being written to, using PowerShell or other methods?

Tags: powershell, operating-system, .net

The thing that I am trying to do is I need to constantly check if a file on a shared corporate network location is available. The network admin performs a copy command and copies a large disk image file .iso to this target network location. The upload (copy) process takes about 4-5 hours, and in order to copy this file to my local computer, I need a way to determine whether this file has been fully copied or not.

I have tried using System.IO.fileinfo::Open, and it worked on my local experiment.
But yesterday when it checks, it failed to tell if the file is locked--the file is not constantly locked, and since it takes 5 hours, it seems that occasionally the file becomes unlocked briefly (possibly due to OS's trying to allocate another continuous space for that file). Hence my powershell script failed.

I also tried checking the size of the file as it is being copied over, but apparently the size of the file is constantly its original size, so this would not work.

So does anyone have any ideas how can this be verified? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a FileSystemWatcher but I am not sure if it works reliably on network folder. Another option is try check last write time of the file, and if the last write time is not changed for, say, 3 minutes, chances are that the copy is finished. You can also combine this with your lock check.